# Replacing directed links with undirected links

Tags: netlogo

I am modeling a material as a lattice of springs (links) connecting material points (agents). Summing the forces acting on the material points using directed links is strait forward (using `link-heading`). However, I would like to use undirected links to increase speed (by reducing number of links by half). The problem is getting the correct direction of the force vector, and calculating force vectors in a computationally efficient manner (i.e. only compute once per link per iteration)

Using directed links (this code works but has twice the necessary number of links):

```
directed-links-breed [springs spring]
springs-own [Fx Fy]

ask springs [let deformation (link-length - natural-length) ;stretch is positive
             let mag-force k * deformation
                 ;;direction of force vector is easy with directed link
             set Fx mag-force * (sin link-heading)
             set Fy mag-force * (cos link-heading)]

;;sum x and y components of force vectors acting on material points
ask material-points [set sigmaFx sum [Fx] of my-out-springs
                     set sigmaFy sum [Fy] of my-out-springs]
```

My attempt to use undirected links:

```
undirected-links-breed [springs spring]
springs-own [Fx Fy force]

ask springs [let deformation (link-length - natural-length) ;stretch is positive
             set force k * deformation]

;;sum x and y components of force vectors acting on material points
;;use of other-end since the link-heading does not necessarily give the correct direction of the force
ask material-points [ask my-springs [set Fx force * sin towards other-end
                                     set Fy force * cos towards other-end]
```

Using this method with undirected links, I get an error "you can't use towards in a link context, because towards is agent/patch-only" , and haven't yet found a way around this. Furthermore, this method would cause each spring (link) to compute force components twice per iteration (once in the direction towards end1 and then again in the direction towards end2), thus this may not be an improvement in speed from using directed links.

Can someone recommend a more computationally efficient way to do this, preferably with undirected links?

Comment: You could store the time that the force was calculated and ask each agent to only calculate it if the time isn't the current time. You could then say something like ask material-points [ ask my-springs with [last-calculated-time != ticks] [ ....]]. Is your simulation running slowly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using myself. You also want to use some error-checking if needed:

```
ask material-points [
     ask my-springs 
     [
       if any? link-neighbors
       [
         let neighbor other-end
         if [distance neighbor] of myself != 0 
         [
             set Fx  force * sin [towards neighbor] of myself
         ]
       ]
     ]
  ]
```